# pyplot: changing font properties on secondary axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex

In a Python plot I would like to use a secondary x-axis to display some alternative values. I'm also quite fond of the latex fonts, and would like those fonts to present throughout the plot. However, I find that when I set up my secondary axis, the latex font disappears. Here's a minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Xvalues = np.linspace(0,10,100)
Yvalues = np.sqrt(Xvalues)
Xticks = np.linspace(0,10,6)

AltXvalues = np.log10(Xvalues+1)
AltLabels = ["%.2f" % x for x in AltXvalues] # Round these values

fig = plt.figure()
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(Xvalues, Yvalues)
ax1.set_xticks(Xticks)
ax1.set_xlabel('$x_1$')
ax1.set_ylabel('$y$')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xlabel('$\\log_{10}\\,(x_1+1)$')
ax2.set_xticks(Xticks)
ax2.set_xticklabels(AltLabels)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

How can I ensure that the latex font is continued on the secondary axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are making those labels into strings when you set `AltLabels`. The different font you see on the primary axis tick labels is because those labels are printed in `LaTeX`'s math-mode. So, the simple fix is to add the math-mode operators to the `AltLabel` strings:

```
AltLabels = ["$%.2f$" % x for x in AltXvalues] # Round these values
```

(Note the `$` signs)

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. That works perfectly. I did have a hunch that it was related to the string conversion, but I didn't know you could use the math environment in the format.